# How can I add Environment related text to Azure AD login page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, customization

As shown in the image I want the text to appear at top relative to environment used:

[image: illustration]

I viewed the **Company Branding** option but there I only saw options for background image and logo .

As for now I don't have credentials to login. Its just R&D work given to me to determine feasibility. I am sure there would be some way, but that I am not getting it. That's why I posted this to Stack Overflow.

Comment: The Company branding will be reflected to the entire tenant level all application. You can't differentiate by the environment as it will show for all application sign-in in tenant. Using company branding you and set 
1.The large illustration and/or its background color
2. The banner logo
3.You can also add text to this area

Please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/customize-sign-in-page?view=o365-worldwide#add-company-branding-to-your-sign-in-page-and-access-panel-pages) for more understanding

Comment: @Raghavendra-MSFTIdentity Your comment looks like it should be an answer, could you add it? :)

Answer (score 1):

The Company branding will be reflected to the entire tenant level(reflected on all application).

You can't differentiate by the environment as it will be show for all application while sign-in.

Using company branding you and set

- The large illustration and/or its background color
- The banner logo
- You can also add text to this area.

Please go through the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/setup/customize-sign-in-page?view=o365-worldwide#add-company-branding-to-your-sign-in-page-and-access-panel-pages) for more understanding